# Highlight.js not working for echo'ed text from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, highlight.js

I am echoing text from PHP to be loaded on my page through an AJAX call on my HTML page. I want Highlight.js to go through this text and highlight the syntax for me. However, it doesn't highlight the text. When I do this directly on the HTML page:

```
<pre>
    <code id=resultDiv style="text-align:right;">
       <p> int main() </p>
    </code>
</pre>
```

it works. The *int main()* is highlighted. However,

```
echo 
    "int main()";
```

or even

```
echo "<p> int main() </p>"
```

to that same resultDiv
from my PHP file to the page doesn't get highlighted.

Is there a fix for this? Why does this happen?

Comment: @stackundeflow forgive me if I skewed the formatting for the subsequent HTML (e.g. via `echo`)... I wanted to improve the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you're loading the content from a PHP page using Ajax.

When using highlight.js it will run through your html and highlight everything after the "load" event, however your Ajax call happens asynchronously after this event, which means the content is loaded after hightlight.js has done its pass.

highlight.js has the [highlightBlock function](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#highlightblock-block) that will trigger the code highlighting pass, in your case it will look like the following line of code

```
hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById("resultDiv"));
```

which you'll have to put **after** your content is added to the DOM

Comment: That worked, thanks! Initially, I tried to do a initHighlighting(), but that didn't work for some reason. I'm glad the highlightBlock works!

Comment: That is because initHighlighting() only binds the highlighting pass to the load event, so nothing will happen when that event already occurred